# I need to add an amount but with 2 conditions in the same column. (DAX PIVOT)

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I need to add an amount but with 2 conditions in the same column.

For example:

`Total Amount = product1 and product2`

I'm trying something like this:

`calculate(sum(amount]);filter([Column1]="product1" && [Column1]="product2"))`

Comment: you are not a new user. Please format your code and ask the problem clearly.

Comment: Riad - the content of the post wasn't worth a down vote as it was understandable to a PowerPivot user.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly steep learning curve on some of the DAX basics but once you get past it then things get easier! Try this:

```
= CALCULATE( 
             SUM(mytable[amount]), 
               mytable[Column1] = "product1" || 
               mytable[Column1] = "product2"
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do an "AND" sum - so to only sum the amount when both criteria are present - you can use this:

```
=CALCULATE( 

 SUM(tablename[amount]),

 tablename[Column1] = "Product1",
 tablename[Column1] = "Product2")
```

The code is basically saying:

```
DO(

(This expression),

Filtering according to this expression,
Filtering according to this expression))
```

When you have more than one filter expression in the Calculate formula (separated by commas), DAX will treat it as an "AND" expression - i.e. it will do the expression only for those values which meet all the criteria you've set according to the filter contexts.

So here, your filter contexts are where Column 1 = Product 1 and where Column 1 = Product 2.

To expand on what Jacob said, once you "get" Calculate, things start making a lot more sense a lot quicker...